# Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'metadata.json'. => I used Firebase Functions. I deployed json file. I can't able to write that json

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-functions, readonly

Here is the error please check and answer me if you have solutions.
I used firebase functions.

```
    Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'metadata.json'
        at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
        at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1524:35)
        at /workspace/index.js:113:8
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at next (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
        at Function.process_params (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
        at next (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the error message, `metadata.json` is located in a read-only directory, hence the error. Firebase Functions has a [read-only filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system), and the only writable part of the filesystem is the `/tmp` directory.

**EDIT:**

If you included your JSON file during deployment, you won't be able to write into it because it will be stored on a read-only directory. If you want to write in it, you must first download it from a bucket and save it on the `/tmp` directory.